# How to dynamically create XML elements in java?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I'm new to java and XML, and I need to know how to create XML elements (like TextView) with java using android studio.

I have an arraylist with some information, and I want to create a for-loop that creates elements containing information from the array.

I imagine it would look something like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.size(); i++) {
    Element textview = document.createElement("TextView");
    textView.content = myArray.get(i);
    document.appendChild(textView);
}
```

Note that I am trying to do this in an app, and already have an XML document.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Normally, you would create `TextView` objects directly and add them to some parent `ViewGroup`, without ever going through xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several questions being asked here at once, but I'll give it a shot!

> I need to know how to create XML elements (like TextView) with java using android studio

The "XML elements" you're talking about here are [Android Views](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View) and using xml tags in a layout xml file is just one way of telling the system to create them. Whether you express views in XML or you write Java code to instantiate them, they will become View objects in your app's memory later.

Creating a layout and views dynamically is possible, but verbose and a little bit non-intuitive because you have to specify the layout parameters in code. For example, you can retrieve a parent `LinearLayout` if you have one in your xml layout with ID `parent` and add a `TextView` to it like this:

```
final LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent);
final TextView text = new TextView(this);
text.setText("Hello World");
linearLayout.addView(text);
```

Certainly, you could do this in a loop:

```
final LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent);
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.size(); i++) {
    final TextView text = new TextView(this);
    text.setText(myArray.get(i));
    linearLayout.addView(text);
}
```

The problem with that approach is that it won't handle scrolling if you add too many views, and it expands your memory usage linearly with the size of your array (by creating a new TextView for every element).

What you probably want to read more about is RecyclerView, which will give you a scrollable, virtual list of Views, that will intelligently reuse the `TextViews` already created, as you scroll. Read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#java)!

Comment: At my current stage in app development recyclerview is too advanced for me. However the scrolling thing was useful to know. I will rather use a listview.